# android mvc java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

when I'am not using *mvc* my program work, but when I turn it java.lang.NullPointerException
I can't understand, I studied the android and java recently

code:

modelbike.java

```
private int[][] bike;
private int leg;
private int height;

public int[][] getBike() {
    return bike;
}

public void setBike(int[][] bike) {
    this.bike = bike;
}

// another Getters and Setters
```

ControllerRoadbike.java

```
Modelbike m = new Modelbike();
public void initRoadbike(){
    final int[][] RoadBike = {
            {165,   0, 142, 64, 43, 65, 44, 66, 45, 67 ..},
            {165,   0, 143, 64, 43, 65, 44, 66, 45, 67 ..},
            .
            .}; // roadbike[][] is 61 x 27
    m.setBike(RoadBike);
}

public ArrayList<String> showHeight(){
        ArrayList<String> height = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=142; i<203; i++){
            height.add(""+i);
        }
        return (height);
}
public ArrayList<String> showLeg(){
    ArrayList<String> leg = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 61; i++) {
        if (m.getBike()[i][2] == m.getHeight()) {
            for (int j = 3; j < 27; j += 2) {
                if (m.getBike()[i][j] != 0) {
                    leg.add("" + m.getBike()[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return (leg);
}
```

Calculate_roadbike.java

```
public class Calculate_roadbike extends ActionBarActivity {

private ControllerRoadbike c = new ControllerRoadbike();
private Modelbike m = new Modelbike();
private Spinner sp_height;
private Spinner sp_Leg;
private Menu mainMenu;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculate_roadbike);
    c.initRoadbike();
    showSpinnerHeight();            
}

private void showSpinnerHeight(){
    sp_height = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_height);
    m.setHeight(Integer.parseInt(sp_height.getSelectedItem().toString()));          
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> 
    (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,c.showHeight());
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp_height.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    sp_height.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(
                    AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        showleg();  
                }
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {    
                }
            });
}

private void showleg(){
    sp_Leg = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_leg);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String> 
    (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,c.showLeg());
    dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource
    (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp_Leg.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
}

}
```

logcat

```
12-13 14:02:21.295: E/AndroidRuntime(3911): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 14:02:21.295: E/AndroidRuntime(3911): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gilsur.cfbike/com.gilsur.cfbike.Calculate_roadbike}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 14:02:21.295: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
12-13 14:02:21.295: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-13 14:02:21.295: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-13 14:02:21.295: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-13 14:02:21.295: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-13 14:02:21.295: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-13 14:02:21.295: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-13 14:02:21.295: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 14:02:21.295: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-13 14:02:21.295: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-13 14:02:21.295: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-13 14:02:21.295: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-13 14:02:21.295: E/AndroidRuntime(3911): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 14:02:21.295: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.gilsur.cfbike.Calculate_roadbike.showSpinnerHeight(Calculate_roadbike.java:119)
12-13 14:02:21.295: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.gilsur.cfbike.Calculate_roadbike.onCreate(Calculate_roadbike.java:36)
12-13 14:02:21.295: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-13 14:02:21.295: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-13 14:02:21.295: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-13 14:02:21.295: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     ... 11 more
```

please help..

Comment: Post the logCat please.

Comment: where is your stacktrace? Which line exactly throws Null pointer exception?

Comment: sp_Leg can be null. are you sure you show right layout correctly ?

Comment: i can't understand, my java is newbie

Comment: Please post Calculate_roadbike.java file and also tell about the line where you get this exception. Without posting exact code where the exception occurs, it's not possible to help in case of Null pointer exceptions.

Comment: What is line 119 in Calculate_roadbike.java ?

Comment: @gauravjain m.setHeight(Integer.parseInt(sp_height.getSelectedItem().toString()));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `sp_height.getSelectedItem()` is `null` because nothing is selected initially. When you call `toString()` on `null` you get a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to check Android documentation. 
From the docs :

```
public Object getSelectedItem ()

Added in API level 1
Returns
The data corresponding to the currently selected item, or null if there is nothing selected.
```

Also, sp_height could be null (But I assume that you've referenced it correctly from xml, so I'll rule out that.)